# Spring secutity OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth2

Ele gera o token

> ```
> {
>     "access_token": "0b42ea14-6a21-44fc-9f65-df60f9130542",
>     "token_type": "bearer",
>     "refresh_token": "3653d5f8-161a-4ee2-b3b5-df9e1da4b9a7",
>     "expires_in": 498,
>     "scope": "bar read write"
> }
> ```

Dá erro 403, conforme imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim ele nem entra no servidor:
O restController está assim:

> ```
> @PostMapping(value = "/pesquisar", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
> public RetornoJackson listar(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody UsuarioDTO dto, BindingResult result) {
> ```

Minhas configurações: **OAuth2**

```
package br.eti.netsoft.authSeguranca.oauth2;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration
            extends
                ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
                    .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/admin/**")
                    .hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR").anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration
            extends
                AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                    .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
                throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("cliente")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code",
                            "refresh_token").scopes("bar", "read", "write")
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(86400)
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID).secret("123")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(500);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }
    }
}
```

**SpringSecurity**

```
package br.eti.netsoft.authSeguranca.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Configuração do Spring

```
package br.eti.netsoft.authSeguranca;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"br.eti.netsoft", ""})
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(524288000);
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(524288070);
        multipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return multipartResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Login e senha do Auth2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode ser ?